# Usar VBA no excel para buscar dados em arquivos .docm localizados em subdiretorios

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, microsoft-word

Bom dia,

Estou com seguinte problema em um código VBA que utilizo no Excel para puxar dados de formulários criados no Word.
Se os arquivos .docm estiverem dentro da mesma pasta eu consigo puxar todos os dados que necessito dos formulários sem problema, o problema é que o número de arquivos ficou mt grande e foi necessário separa-los em subdiretórios para uma melhor organização.
Segue abaixo meu código:

```
Sub getWordFormData()
    Dim wdApp As Object, myDoc As Object
    Dim myFolder As String, strFile As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    myFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

    If Len(Dir(myFolder)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox myFolder & vbCrLf & "Not Found", vbInformation, "Cancelled - getWordFormData"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    With ActiveSheet
        .Cells.Clear
        With .Range("A1:F1")
            .Value = Array("Nome", "NIS", "CPF", "Endereço", "CEP", "Bairro")
            .Font.Bold = True
        End With

        strFile = Dir(myFolder & "\*.docm", vbNormal)
        i = 1

        While strFile <> ""
            i = i + 1

            On Error Resume Next

            Set myDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=myFolder & "\" & strFile, ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)

            .Cells(i, 1).Value = myDoc.txtNome.Text
            .Cells(i, 2).Value = myDoc.txtNis.Text
            .Cells(i, 3).Value = myDoc.txtCpf.Text
            .Cells(i, 4).Value = myDoc.txtEnd.Text
            .Cells(i, 5).Value = myDoc.txtCep.Text
            .Cells(i, 6).Value = myDoc.Combobox1.Value

            myDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
            strFile = Dir()
        Wend

        wdApp.Quit
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End With

End Sub
```

Existe alguma forma de modificar este código para que ele consiga buscar os dados dos formulários .docm que estão dentro dos subdiretórios?

Edit

Exemplo: Tenho a pasta do mês de junho e dentro dela tenho 50 pastas cada uma com um formulário .docm, queria executar o excel de dentro da pasta junho e pegar os dados dos formulários que estão dentro dos subdiretórios.

Desde já muito obrigado!!!

Comment: Mude o caminho do diretório? `myFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"` para `myFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Subdiretorio\"`, em que `ThisWorkbook.Path` é o caminho do arquivo Excel. Ou você pode adicionar uma variável de subdiretório, em que é possível escolher qual pasta é escolhida. Ou digitando manualmente, ou com um combobox

Comment: Bom dia, obrigado pela sugestão. Mas o que preciso seria que o código buscasse dentro de diversos subdiretórios automaticamente. Por exemplo: Tenho a pasta do mês de junho e dentro dela tenho 50 pastas cada uma com um formulário .docm, queria executar o excel de dentro da pasta junho e pegar os dados dos formulários de dentro dos subdiretórios. Deu pra entender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há várias maneiras de contornar este problema, duas delas são:

1. O usuário escolhe a subpasta;
2. Você recebe os dados de todas as Subpastas.

#### Escolher a subpasta

Um código de exemplo de como escolher a pasta desejada, utilizando o FileDialog, então `myFolder` seria alterado para:

```
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim myFolder As String

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Escolha a pasta"
        .Show
    End With
    On Error Resume Next
    myFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1) & "\"

    If myFolder = "" Then
        GoTo CleanExit                           'Se a pasta estiver vazia
    End If

    'Seu código aqui

CleanExit:

    Set fso = Nothing
```

#### Dados de todas as subpastas

Ou os dados de todas as subpastas podem ser obtidos com a seguinte função em um módulo:

```
Option Explicit
Public myFolder As String
Sub teste()
    Dim subpastas As Variant

    subpastas = Listar_Subpastas

    For i = LBound(subpastas) To UBound(subpastas)
        Debug.Print subpastas(i)
    Next i
End Sub

Public Function Listar_Subpastas() As Variant
    ''''''''''''''''''''
    '==== Arquivos ===='
    ''''''''''''''''''''
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim xPath As String
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim fso As Object, folder1 As Object
    Dim ncell As Long
    Dim fso_FOLDER As Object
    Dim fso_FILE As Object
    Dim vaArray     As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    On Error Resume Next
    xPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    Set fso_FOLDER = fso.GetFolder(xPath)

    If xPath = "" Then
        GoTo CleanExit                           'Se a pasta estiver vazia
    End If

    'https://stackoverflow.com/a/31428399/7690982
    'Encontra todos os Arquivos
    ReDim vaArray(1 To fso_FOLDER.Subfolders.Count)
    i = 1
    If fso_FOLDER.Files.Count > 0 Then
        ''Loop through each SubFolder in Folder
        For Each fso_FILE In fso_FOLDER.Subfolders
            vaArray(i) = fso_FILE
            i = i + 1
        Next fso_FILE
    Else
        MsgBox "Nenhuma subpasta encontrada em " & xPath
    End If

    'For i = LBound(vaArray) To UBound(vaArray)
    '    Debug.Print vaArray(i)
    'Next i

    Listar_Subpastas = vaArray

    'Sair do código
CleanExit:

    Set fso = Nothing
    Set fso_FOLDER = Nothing
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Function
```

Ou um código pode ser realizado para ao invés de obter as subpastas do mesmo caminho que o arquivo Excel, o usuário possa selecionar a pasta principal.

E uma ComboBox `ComboBox1` pode ser criada em um formulário `Userform1` com as subpastas. Então um botão pode ser criado para atribuir o caminho da subpasta desejada em uma variável global, no caso do exemplo `myFolder`:

[image: Userform]

E o código do formulário para preencher a ComboBox e o botão:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    myFolder= ComboBox1.Value
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim subpastas As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    With ComboBox1
        .Clear
        subpastas = Listar_Subpastas

        For i = LBound(subpastas) To UBound(subpastas)
            .AddItem subpastas(i)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Desculpe a minha ignorância, mas essa e apenas a terceira vez que lido com VBA e não tenho muito conhecimento. Poderia me indicar como faria pra aplicar sua segunda opção "Dados de todas as subpastas" juntamente com o código que coloquei na pergunta? Tentei de diversas formas e não obtive sucesso. Consigo ver a lista com as subpastas mas não consigo puxar os dados dos .docm que estão dentro delas pra planilha. Muito obrigado novamente!!!

Comment: @FabricioAndrade Editei a resposta, você utiliza a variável global `myFolder` no Userform. E deleta no seu código a linha `myFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"`. Ou substitui a variável `myFolder` pela variável global com o Subdiretório desejado.

Comment: Muito obrigado estou conseguindo desenvolver o que queria com suas dicas. Agora se não for pedir demais, teria como, usando o FileDialog selecionar varias pastas de uma vez ou selecionar uma e ele pegar todas as subpastas? Achei como fazer com arquivos mas não com pastas. Obrigado novamente!!!

Comment: @FabricioAndrade Crie outra pergunta sobre isso, se não a resposta começa a ficar muito grande e foge da sua dúvida inicial. Pois este é um site de Q & A, para ajudar outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida no futuro.